# How do I enable comments for forum like statuses module?

Tags: views, 7, ajax, comments

i used this module  project statuses  (drupal 7) 
i want that write comment for forum like above module.
how can i do assign statuses style to comments forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant, the [statuses](http://drupal.org/project/statuses) module has quite a different concept and doesn't have anything to do with content-types commenting(e.g drupal forum), but if your problem is just to make your forum comments look like statuses, you can simply achieve that via some styling or templating your forum comment tpl file (better approach). for the sake of Ajax, you can use [Ajax Comments](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) module, but its not so much stable yet.
if you still need further help don't hesitate to ask!